# _path is giving the relational id rather than the objects id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to link_to like this:

```
    <% @folder.contents.each do |content| %>
        <%=  link_to content_path do %>
          <%=  image_tag content.mfile.url(:thumbnail) %>
        <% end %>
       ...
```

At this point content looks like this:

```
[6] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f30f8846568>>)> content
=> #<Content:0x007f30fb9add40
 id: 41,
 name: "jjjjjj",
 url: nil,
 created_at: Tue, 18 Apr 2017 13:36:51 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 18 Apr 2017 13:36:51 UTC +00:00,
 mfile_file_name: "Selection_016.png",
 mfile_content_type: "image/png",
 mfile_file_size: 71534,
 mfile_updated_at: Tue, 18 Apr 2017 13:36:51 UTC +00:00,
 folder_id: 5>
```

Problem is content_path is being given as:

```
[7] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f30f8846568>>)> content_path
=> "/contents/5"
```

When I want 41.

Any explanation or help to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried: `link_to content_path(content)`?

Comment: What is the 41? The `id`?

Comment: @jvillian ok that worked, any idea why content_path references the folder id rather than its own id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
  <%=  link_to content_path(content) do %>
```

When you do this:

```
  <%=  link_to content_path do %>
```

Rails tries to guess at the appropriate `id` to use in generating the path. I'm guessing `5` is the `id` for `@folder` and that your params includes `{..., id: 5, ...}`. So, if I have that right, then Rails looks in params for an id, finds `5`, and uses that as a guess for `content_path`.

When you do:

```
  <%=  link_to content_path(content) do %>
```

You don't let Rails guess, you tell Rails what object to use for `id`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake. If you do not give id to any rails routes path, it guesses the id it has from url or params.

If you are using a path root which directs to another id You must specify the id it has to use to create a path which you can specify here as

```
<%=  link_to content_path(id: content.id) do %>
```

The id 5 you are specifying here must be the id from url or from params. try checking params before your do loop and you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

`content_path` is a method generated by the configuration you put in your routes file. You can pass in the param as suggested, or use this

```
<%=  link_to content do %>
```

And rails will know to call the `content_path` method with the content instance as the param.